# Issue with .INF file for registering ActiveX

Tags: c#, .net, activex, registry

I have made an INF file, its contents are as follows

```
[version]
Signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
MyControl.dll=MyControl.dll


; Now installing the ActiveX
[MyControl.dll]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={05B7BC83-FCA1-452d-9D33-193784FEC637}
FileVersion=1,0,0,1
RegisterServer=yes
```

but the Control is not registered after Internet Explorer has finished installation, and each time I press F5 to refresh the webpage, my browser shows the Installation prompt.?? which means that it is not installed in my machine. And when I run `regasm /tlb /codebase MyControl.dll` command it starts working fine... I have written my ActiveX control in C# and here are registering function

```
[ComRegisterFunction()]
        public static void RegisterClass ( string key )
        {
            // Strip off HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ from the passed key as I don't need it
            StringBuilder   sb = new StringBuilder ( key ) ;

            sb.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\","") ;
            // Open the CLSID\{guid} key for write access
            RegistryKey k   = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(),true);

            // And create   the 'Control' key - this allows it to show up in
            // the ActiveX control container
            RegistryKey ctrl = k.CreateSubKey   ( "Control" ) ;
            ctrl.Close ( ) ;

            // Next create the CodeBase entry   - needed if not string named and GACced.
            RegistryKey inprocServer32 = k.OpenSubKey   ( "InprocServer32" , true ) ;
            inprocServer32.SetValue (   "CodeBase" , Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase ) ;
            inprocServer32.Close ( ) ;
                // Finally close the main   key
            k.Close (   ) ;
            //MessageBox.Show("Registered");
        }
```

Please help me out that why `RegisterServer=yes` is not calling this function, and I have to call it manually using `regasm /tlb /codebase MyControl.dll` command?

Comment: did u ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I make a workarround for that... as RegisterServer=yes is not working.. I have made an other executable file in C#, and bundled the final .cab file with my executable file and "RegAsm.exe" and from my executable I am calling RegAsm.exe with specified arrguments.. it works fine for me.. if anyproblem let me know

Comment: Look at this
http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/installation2/how-can-i-install-a-inf-file-from-the-command-line-.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit more detail on how to implement Ummar's workaround in the [Downloading C# ActiveX Components through CAB File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Deployment.aspx?msg=2619109#xx2619109xx) article on CodeProject

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried it - only found the article a week after I resorted to using ATL and C++ :-( ).

Answer (score 1):

When the CAB content specified with RegisterServer=yes is registered, it uses regsvr32.  Your C# assembly requires regasm, therefore you need an additional mechanism to enforce regasm.  The suggested way is with an msi package, which will give the user a way to uninstall your component.